# plone how to add content rule for event which after end date should be moved to another folder

Tags: python, plone

I wish to create a content rule for an event such that **after expiry date of the event i.e end date**, it should be moved to another folder. How do I specify the content rule. Please guide. Using Plone 4.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure you can do this with a content rule; there is no code running at that exact time. You'd need to run an external cron job to trigger a scan for expired events.

Why not just use a collection to list expired events in the other location?